# Magento 2: Is it possible to add a canonical link to a page through it's layout file?

Tags: magento2, layout, canonical

I have a custom page and I'm trying to add a canonical link to it. I see that in the layout file I can specify meta data in the head node. Is it possible to add the canonical link in the layout as well? Or what is the "right" way to add it to a custom page?
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hope you are looking for this one

```
<head>
      <link rel="canonical" src="pageurl" src_type="url"/>
</head>
```

Please change the 'pageurl' as per your requirements. And place it in custom layout section in admin , if you want the functionality using admin custom layout section.

I have used this with one of my category.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Dinesh's answer, you can also use the {{baseUrl}} variable if you want to make the URL dynamic.

```
<head>
    <link rel="canonical" src="{{baseUrl}}mypath" src_type="url"/>
</head>
```